# Pandas: If condition on multiple columns having null values and fillna with 0

Tags: pandas

I have a below dataframe, and my requirement is that, if both columns have `np.nan` then no change, if either of column has empty value then fill na with `0` value. I wrote this code but why its not working. Please suggest.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Age': [np.nan, np.nan, 22, np.nan, 50,99],
        'Salary': [217, np.nan, 262, 352, 570, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

cond1 = (df['Age'].isnull()) & (df['Salary'].isnull())
if cond1 is False:
    df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(0)
    df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just assign it with update

```
c = ['Age','Salary']
df.update(df.loc[~df[c].isna().all(1),c].fillna(0))

df
Out[341]: 
    Age  Salary
0   0.0   217.0
1   NaN     NaN
2  22.0   262.0
3   0.0   352.0
4  50.0   570.0
5  99.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c1 = df['Age'].isna()
c2 = df['Salary'].isna()

df[np.c_[c1 & ~c2, ~c1 & c2]]=0   
df
    Age  Salary
0   0.0   217.0
1   NaN     NaN
2  22.0   262.0
3   0.0   352.0
4  50.0   570.0
5  99.0     0.0
```

Comment: Hi onyambu, loved that answer. Just trying to break it down though for future use..would you mind explaining what 'np.c_' does exactly in this context ?

Comment: @DanielWeigel it concatenates two series into an array

Comment: I see... so you convert your masks into arrays before subsetting your df with it..I guess you would do that when you want to match the column dimensions of your original df ?

Comment: @DanielWeigel yes

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp=df.loc[(df['Age'].isna() & df['Salary'].isna())]
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.loc[tmp.index]=np.nan
```

This might be a bit less sophisticated than the other answers but worked for me:

- I first save the row(s) containing both Nan values at the same time
- then fillna the original df as per normal
- then set np.nan back to the location where we saved both rows containing Nan at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows that are all nulls and use `where` to exclude them during the fill:

```py
bools = df.isna().all(axis = 1)
df.where(bools, df.fillna(0))
    Age  Salary
0   0.0   217.0
1   NaN     NaN
2  22.0   262.0
3   0.0   352.0
4  50.0   570.0
5  99.0     0.0
```

Your if statement won't work because you need to check each row for True or False; `cond1` is a series, and cannot be compared correctly to False (it will just return False, which is not entirely true), there can be multiple False and True in the series.

An inefficient way would be to traverse the rows:

```py
  for row, index in zip(cond1, df.index):
     if not row:
         df.loc[index] = df.loc[index].fillna(0)
```

apart from the inefficiency, you are keeping track of index positions; the pandas options try to abstract the process while being quite efficient, since the looping is in C